# communicating angular with sails js using http post()

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js

I am using angular js and sails js in my project. I am getting problem with **http get()** while sending data with special characters from angular to sails.

I want to use **http post()** instead of http get(). Can anybody help ?
My code looks like

```
var employee = $scope.employee;
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/employee/saveEmployee',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},

        data: {"empName":"employee .empName",
               "age":"employee .age",
                "designation":"employee .designation",
                "empType":"employee .empType"

                }

    }).success(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

Comment: please include part of current code having issues. http post is fairly simple for angular : `$http.post('/someUrl', {msg:'hello word!'})` and does not require changes on sails side in general.

Comment: @arkoak above I have provided sample code snipet and it gives 
500 (Internal Server Error) and I am finding undefined in sails side...

Comment: angular code seems ok,  you can output some vars to console using console.log and try to find the exact problem statement, then share that part of the code as well alongwith the actual problem description you get in the console.

Comment: "*I am finding undefined in sails side...*" what do you mean ? Please provide some console output, error message or something. A 500 always leads in an error logged in the console.

Comment: Its worked ....
Just removed the Double code " " from Json like this::
data: {
empName:employee .empName,
               age:employee .age,
                designation:employee .designation,
                empType:employee .empType

                }

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a sails generated API, just change your url to `/employee/create`

Sails automatically generates standard CRUD routes that you can use out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Its worked ....I have put the json in improper format.
Just removed the Double code " " from Json like this::

```
data: {
               empName:employee .empName,
               age:employee .age,
                designation:employee .designation,
                empType:employee .empType

                }
```